# Difference between revisions of a list is shown as complete rewrite of the list

Tags: bug, revisions-list, diff

I've come across a strange display of a difference between two revisions of a list in a post, where in a newer revision only one bullet point was changed: the "inline" and "side-by-side" differences look as if the whole list has been completely rewritten. See the following screenshots of [this page at ru.SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1268/revisions) (the place where I first found it; not sure how to search for edited lists on other SE sites).

### Actual change, "side-by-side markdown" view

[image: screenshot of side-by-side markdown diff]

---

### Side-by-side diff

[image: screenshot of side-by-side diff]

Inline diff shows basically the same problem as side-by-side one, only the large red wall of text is above the green one.

Comment: And it only seems to have started around revision 39 (I tried some of the ones before 39, and the diffs were correctly shown)